# Remove Specific Events From URL string using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, regex, xss

I have a URL

```
http://www.example.com/" onmouseover="alert('howdy')
```

In this URL I wanted to remove all events like `onmouserover`, `onmouseclick`, etc.

I have tried below code to extract just `URL` from `String`:

```
function UrlExtract(Url) {

var pattern = new RegExp(/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm);
Url = String(Url).match(pattern);
return Url;
}
```

What I want is user to specify which events to be removed from a `Url` string and only those events should get removed.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Is it the actual URL? your example here contains white space before onmouseover. provide URL with 2-3 events

Comment: http://www.example.com/" onmouseover="alert('howdy')

this is not an actual URL but we are trying to prevent url for XSS attack. So we want to remove specific events from url

Comment: example.com/"; onmouseover="alert('howdy'); onclick="alert('click')"; onmouseout="alert('out')". something like that?

Comment: Yes .  These events getting executed while we tested it. So we want to remove these events.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
var url = "example.com/; onmouseover=alert('howdy');onclick=alert('click'); onmouseout=alert('out')"
function removeString(originalStr, strArr) {
    if(strArr.constructor === Array) {
       for(var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
          originalStr = originalStr.replace(strArr[i], '');
       }
    }
    return oriStr;
}
console.log(removeString(url, [" onclick=alert('click');", " onmouseover=alert('howdy');"]));
//output: "example.com/; onmouseout=alert('out')"
```